# How can I set a div to position:fixed, when scrolling it to the browsers top?

Tags: jquery, css, position

I hope I can describe my problem:

I have a shopping basket div with price information below a header (logo, topnav) on my page. When scrolling down the page, I want the shopping basket div to stop scrolling (position:fixed), when it touches the upper end of the browser...

Does anyone have a keyword for what I'm looking for?

Thanks

Jan

Comment: This might help: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/sticky-scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine that you have jQuery and your shopping basket has class 'cart'

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
   if($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.cart').offset().top){
      // Add position:fixed styling (eg. with a specific class)
   } else {
      // Remove position:fixed styling
   }
});
```

Comment: Very close: The if condition works, but the else condition (when scrolling back) has no effect...
But thanks so far.

Comment: Oh, correct :) When your .cart is fixed, its `$('.cart').offset().top` will change from the original (will be document_scroll_top + your indent from css). You should use in IF another element, but on the same height as your .cart

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sounds plausible :-) That helps.